# celery does not work with inheritance and properties decorator

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, celery, decorator

I am trying to use inheritance with celery

Here my classes:

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def var(self):
    return self._var

  @var.setter
  def var(self, value):
    self._var = value

  def b(self):
    self.var = 'b'

class B(A):
  @celeryapp.task(name='B.b', filter=task_method)
  def b(self):
    super(B, self).b()
```

Here my main code:

```
# instanciate B
instb = B()
# Send a task to celery
instb.b.delay()
```

Celery output logs:

```
[2014-01-24 12:48:11,407: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: B.b[57833124-7691-443a-ad5a-d7caea4578d3]
```

So far so good, but when i try to get var property

```
print instb.var()
# or
print instb.var
```

python says:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_var'
```

Someone can explain to me why it does not work ?
Thanks

Comment: U should try `b.var()` .

Comment: `var` is a `@property`, so `var()` will give a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

Neither `A` nor `B` has an `__init__` method, which means that the `_var` attribute does not exist until `instance.b()` runs or `instance.var` (or, directly, `instance._var`) is assigned. You can initialise this attribute to avoid the error:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = None
```

However, the broader problem is that you are expecting `b()` to have run by the time you call `print b.var` (shouldn't that be `instb.var`?) You need to get the result of your task then wait for it to finish:

```
result = instb.b.delay()
result.get()
print instb.var
```

See the documentation on [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) and [calling tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#calling-the-task).

Comment: You are right, it's instb.var() that i want. But it was a copy/paste error. I will try to initialize classes.

Comment: Initializing A class permit to avoid the AttributeError indeed. But instb.var is set to None instead of 'b'.

Comment: Yes, that's because the `b` method still isn't actually being called. Read the links posted in the second half of my answer.

Comment: b method is called properly, if i put a print inside it works and i will see it in celery output. But when i want to add an attribute to my instance, whatever it is, it will not save the attribute.

Comment: Then perhaps celery is provided with a copy of `instb`, which it mutates, leaving the original unaltered. You may have to refactor your code to explicitly `return` what you need from the task.